# iPhone Application records sounds and saves those sounds

Tags: iphone, audio, storage

My application will record and store some sounds to play them back later. Right now, I can record the sound which is saved in temporary folder.

Where is the best way to store sounds to play back later?
Do I need database or just store as files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files in your Documents directory. Or perhaps a subdirectory within Docs. Using a subdirectory has the advantage that you may want to store other data files somewhere in Docs dir, but keeping all the sound recordings in their own location lets you iterate through the files or delete the entire directory and its contents. I've seen plenty of messages suggesting it's less efficient and/or fast to store a bunch of binary objects in SQLite.